# How to get window.scroll bottom height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to find scroll bottom height, but I have not find any solution. Using `$(window).scrollTop()` we can get the top height. How can we find the bottom height?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by

```
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
```